# Auto send Email from Sheets Using Google Scrip

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate an email system where whenever someone submits a form, therefore editing the spreadsheet, google-scripts will send me an email containing the message. The code works perfectly fine and does what I want. However, I need to manually run the script every time which defeats the purpose. I have tried to do the function onEdit(e) however it never worked. I have also tried the triggers feature of AppsScript with no luck.

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emailAddress = 'email@email.com'; // First column
  var message = data[0][3]; // Fourth column;
  var subject = 'A Subject';//this will always be the same
  Logger.log(emailAddress, subject, message); //This is to test because of the limit of how many emails you can send a day.
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Here is a link to a google sheet that you can test and edit the script on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bBNDc33fBx2JPcRByt-8TA2vrLqa51H72TIM-SeARsc/edit?usp=sharing

The sheets is not using google forms, it is getting it's data from the results of an HTML webpage I built that is used as a form.

Comment: If you’re talking about using the on edit trigger that only responds to user changes read the documentation. Or just do it from the form on submit

Comment: If this is supposed to be fired from a google form, did you try the onSubmit Trigger ?

Comment: whats up with the email address?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#new-editor).

Follow these steps once you created the form inside your sheets:

**For New Editor**

> - Open your Apps Script project.
> - At the left, click Triggers alarm.
> - At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
> - Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.
> - Click Save.

**For Legacy Editor**

> - From the script editor, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
> - Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
> - Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.
> - Under Events, select either Time-driven or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From spreadsheet).
> - Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for example, an > > - Hour timer that runs Every hour or an On open trigger).
> - Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you are contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
> - Click Save.

For this scenario, **Select event source**: *From spreadsheet* and **Select event type**: *On form submit*.

Once the setup for Installable trigger is done, you can now add an event object *e* to the function parameter to access the form values submitted by the user.

Try this in your code:

```
function onSubmitForm(e){
  var message = e.namedValues["Message"];   //get the message value using question name
  var emailAddress = 'xxxxxsampleemailxxxxxx';
  var subject = 'A Subject';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); //send email
}
```

**Example:**

[image: Forms]

[image: Sheets]

**Output:**

[image: Sample Email]

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#new-editor)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: I am not using google forms to submit data. I am using a HTML page that sends the results of a form in the style of a webpage. I did the steps for the trigger however you lost me at the code. Is there a way to edit what I have using the 'e' object?

Comment: @Ramy CoreMT - Could you attach snippet of your HTML and the code where you send the data?